# when i trying to use API this appeared The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart

[image: the imageUrl][image: this is the api from json]

when i trying to use API this appeared The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Comment: Please paste the code as text in the question body using the Code Sample option {}.

Comment: a quick fix would be to add `!` behing it, like `space.imageUrl!` but I suggest you to read https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety to understand what it means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it gives such an error because flutter has a null safety feature. Try `Image.asset(space.imageUrl!)` or just assign a default value for your variable. Ex: `Image.asset(space.imageUrl ?? "imageUrl failed to load")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (space.imageUrl != null) Image.asset(space.imageUrl!),
```

or

```
Image.asset(space.imageUrl ?? "assets/img/img_not_available.jpeg"),
```